# What exactly does the Bootstrap form-group CSS class do?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot find any clear documentation on what the Bootstrap "form-group" class does. Sometimes I add it when forms don't format how I want and other times I remove it for the same reason. Sometimes it makes too much spacing between rows, depending on which classes are used on input elements. I usually try to do without it, letting fields automatically wrap as needed depending on their size (grid cells used). That avoids micro-managing row breaks.

And it also acts different on different browser brands and versions and with different widget types present. For example, it may be fine under browser version X before I add a check-box, but act different on *just* version X when I add the check-box. This organic trial and error consumes a lot of time "micro-fiddling". I wonder if there's not a more exacting explanation on what it does and why. This includes both "horizontal" forms and regular forms.

I've searched around at getbootstrap.com without finding anything specific. That's the closest to "official" documentation I can find. Is there a better resource?

In additional to technical info, I wonder if there is info on the name choice, philosophy, and recommended usage of it; including exclusion scenarios. In other words, what did the creator(s) of "form-group" *intend*? That may help one relate to its usage.

```
<!-- Typical usage for reference -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput">
</div>
```

Comment: It's kinda funny that for all the ranting about younger developers, solving this didn't need any of that "mass trial-and-error" - it just needed you to look in the Bootstrap `.css` file for where `.form-group` is defined/used. No AI work necessary.

Comment: Re: "all you need to do is look at Bootstrap's CSS" [paraphrased] -- Can't Bootstrap's JavaScript also be involved? I don't believe one can safely assume that the only thing that acts on a given Bootstrap class is just CSS, and not JavaScript, but please correct me if I'm wrong. (While one can search for CSS class names in the .JS, that won't catch dynamically computed names.)

Comment: Bootstrap's JS is limited to very specific scenarios - it's entirely optional, and many Bootstrap sites don't need it at all. None of them dynamically generate new class names; they occasionally add/remove a class to an element. (Even if they did, *starting* in Bootstrap's CSS would be a good choice; `.form-group` won't be hard to find in there.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find out what `form-group` does is to look at the [source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) or the [compiled CSS](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css).

In the compiled CSS, `form-group` is found twice.

**1: Adds a margin at the bottom of the form:**

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

**2: Formats for screens over 576px:**

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .form-inline label {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .form-inline .form-group {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
...
```

1. `display: flex;`
2. `flex: 0 0 auto;` Is shorthand for `flex-grow: 0;`, `flex-basis: 0;` and `flex-shrink: auto;`.
3. `flex-flow: row wrap;` Flex items will be displayed in rows and will wrap.
4. `align-items: center;` Flex items will be centered in the cross-axis. CSSTricks has a [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/) on this.
5. `margin-bottom: 0;` A bottom margin of 1rem will only be visible on screens smaller than 576px.